# .is_valid() method but is not validating when ajax used

Tags: python, html, jquery, django, ajax

when i used ajax in my project the form.is_valid() method not validating the form. it showing the 'this field required error' but i access that using request.POST means i fill all the fields.

'''
this is html code which render the django model form

```
   ##HTML FORM##

        <form action=""  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="reception_form" novalidate> {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field1 in form1   %}
                    <label for="{{field1.id_for_label}}"> {{field1.label}} </label> {{field1}}
                    <div>
                    {% if field1.errors %}{% for error in field1.errors %} <small class="errorlist">{{error}}</small> {% endfor %}{% endif %}
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
                
                {% for field2 in reception  %}
                    {% if field2.name != 'gender' %}
                        <label for=" {{field2.id_for_label}} "> {{field2.label}} </label> {{field2}}
                        <div>
                            {% if field2.errors %}{% for error in field2.errors %} <small class="errorlist">{{error}}</small> {% endfor %}{% endif %}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
        
                {% for radiofield in reception.gender  %}
                
                        {{radiofield.tag}}
                        <label for=" {{radiofield.id_for_label}} "> {{radiofield.choice_label}} </label> <br>
                {% endfor %}
               
               
               <input type="submit" value="Add Reception" name="Add Reception" class="btn btn-secondary mb-3" >
                 
                
            </form>
        
        
        ----------
        ## Ajax ##
        $('#reception_form').submit(function(e){
    console.log(" submit pressed")
    e.preventDefault();
        let Rnm = $('#id_username').val();
        let Rfnm = $('#id_first_name').val();
        let Rlnm = $('#id_last_name').val();
        let Rem = $('#id_email').val();
        let Rpwd = $('#id_password1').val();
        let Rmob = $('#id_mob_no').val();
        let Rcty= $('#id_city').val();
        let Rdob = $('#id_dob').val();
        let Rpr = $('#id_profile_photo').val();
        let Rgen = $("input[name='gender']:checked").val()
        let Rcsr = $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val()
       
        reception_data = {Rusername : Rnm , Rfirst_name:Rfnm ,Rlast_name:Rlnm ,Remail:Rem , Rpassword:Rpwd, RmMob_no:Rmob , Rcity:Rcty , RBirth_Date :Rdob, Rprofile:Rpr, Rgender:Rgen , csrfmiddlewaretoken:Rcsr};
        //console.log(reception_data)
        $.ajax({
            url: "{% url 'AddReception' %}" ,
            type : 'POST',
            data : reception_data,
            dataType:'json',
            success: function(data){
                console.log("ajax executed");
                console.log(data);
                
            }

        });
});
----------
```

admin_home view render the initial form and user information

```
    ## views ##
    ## 1) home##
    def Admin_home(request):
        print("admin Home")
        user = request.user
        admin = Admin.objects.get(pk=user)
        # print(request)
        form1 = Register()
        reception = Register_Reception()
        param = {'user':user , 'admin':admin , 'form1':form1 , 'reception':reception}
        return render(request , "patients/admin/home.html" , param)
 

----------
This view function handles the ajax request but is_valid() returns false

    ## 2) Add Reception ##
    def Add_reception(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form1 = Register(request.POST) #usercreation form
            form2 = Register_Reception(request.POST , request.FILES) #reception profile form
            print(form1.is_valid())
            print(form1.errors)
            print(request.POST['Rpassword'])
        return HttpResponse("form submited")
```

'''

Comment: Hi prasad, This question will be easier to understand and may attract an answer if you format that code snippet in the middle of the question to make it tidier. It's hard to see what .submit() is returning

Comment: the required code is now updated

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using jquery, right? Then i would try to serialize the form data like this:

```
reception_data = $("#reception_form").serialize()
```

Maybe this is better to send the POST data to the form...

Best,
jingo

Comment: is_valid() is not working . i am getting all the data in views by request.POST